# How to avoid duplicate information from HTML with .querySelectorAll in VBA?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to collect data from a website, which stores information about vehicle accidents in the US. For this I need to loop through all the cases on the website and store the tables in an Excel sheet, so that I can reformat this data to receive a CSV of all listed accidents.

I got most of the code from the user "QHarr" (thank you again) and so far the code works fine and collects all the data with a .querySelectorAll("table"). Unfortunately, it appears that the code takes the same information twice in specific situations. I think the reason for this is that some tables are nested within other tables and therefore the nested tables are copied twice to the sheet (sometimes even in a different format). I tried to work around this by adding if conditions which check for certain keywords but did not succeed.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim initialLinksURL As String, i As Long, j As Long, newURL As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    initialLinksURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Search"

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ie As Object, caseLinks As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 initialLinksURL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set caseLinks = .document.querySelectorAll("[href*='CaseID=']")     

        Dim linksAndIds()
        ReDim linksAndIds(1 To caseLinks.Length, 1 To 2)
        For i = 0 To caseLinks.Length - 1
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 1) = caseLinks.Item(i)
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 2) = Replace$(caseLinks.Item(i), "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=", vbNullString)
        Next

        For i = LBound(linksAndIds, 1) To UBound(linksAndIds, 1)

            newURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=false" '"https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewPage&xsl=Case.xsl&tab=Crash&form=CaseForm&baseNode=&vehnum=-1&occnum=-1&pos=-1&pos2=-1&websrc=true&title=Crash%20Overview%20-%20Summary&caseid=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&year=&fullimage=false"
            .Navigate2 newURL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Dim tables As Object

            Set tables = .document.querySelectorAll("table")


            For j = 0 To tables.Length - 1
                clipboard.SetText tables.Item(j).outerHTML


                If Not CBool(InStr(tables.Item(j).outerHTML, "Scene Photos")) And Not CBool(InStr(tables.Item(j).outerHTML, "Image ID: ")) _
                    And Not CBool(InStr(tables.Item(j).outerHTML, "Braint")) _
                    And UBound(Split(tables.Item(j).outerHTML, "subtable")) <= 1 Then       'no images and avoid duplicate tables

                    clipboard.PutInClipboard
                    ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
                End If
            Next
        Next

        .Quit
    End With

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

I was thinking about getting the deepest HTML element/child, but I could not figure out how to do this or if this even solves my problem.

Thank you ever so much.

Comment: How to populate the result and what is it you wanna parse from there @Noco?

Comment: Can you provide an example url where duplicate information is written out please?

Comment: @QHarr : For example if we look at the first case (Case ID: 2004-04-089), the code duplicates the tables which start with the heading "Measurements (in centimeters)". Also, the table "Vehicle 1 Occupant 1 - Injury Codes" is duplicated in two different formats.

Comment: I’ll have a look. Did you run the code below and have the same problem?

Comment: @SIM : Basically, I want a CSV file which groups information of the same type in columns. For example, if there is a table with vehicle properties (e.g. mass, size, etc.) I want the information of all cases to be listed in the same column(s) so that the data is comparable and can be evaluated. Does this answer your question?

Comment: but which tables specifically are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can work to improve this but I am not seeing where the duplicate comes in. If data occurs at constant indices across pages you restrict the tables you write out, for example, using an array holding the indices of interest

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim initialLinksURL As String, i As Long, j As Long, newURL As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    initialLinksURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Search"

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ie As Object, caseLinks As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 initialLinksURL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set caseLinks = .document.querySelectorAll("[href*='CaseID=']")

        Dim linksAndIds()
        ReDim linksAndIds(1 To caseLinks.Length, 1 To 2)
        For i = 0 To caseLinks.Length - 1
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 1) = caseLinks.item(i)
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 2) = Replace$(caseLinks.item(i), "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=", vbNullString)
        Next

        For i = LBound(linksAndIds, 1) To UBound(linksAndIds, 1)

            newURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=false" '"https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewPage&xsl=Case.xsl&tab=Crash&form=CaseForm&baseNode=&vehnum=-1&occnum=-1&pos=-1&pos2=-1&websrc=true&title=Crash%20Overview%20-%20Summary&caseid=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&year=&fullimage=false"
            .Navigate2 newURL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Dim tables As Object

            Set tables = .document.querySelectorAll("table")
            Dim arr()
            arr = Array(0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

            For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                clipboard.SetText tables.item(arr(j)).outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial

            Next
        Next

        .Quit
    End With

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

**Debugging script:**

To aid debugging and duplicates and for ease of reading the following script is amended to write out each case to a new worksheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTables()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Dim initialLinksURL As String, i As Long, j As Long, newURL As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    initialLinksURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/LegacyCDS/Search"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ie As Object, caseLinks As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 initialLinksURL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set caseLinks = .document.querySelectorAll("[href*='CaseID=']")

        Dim linksAndIds()
        ReDim linksAndIds(1 To caseLinks.Length, 1 To 2)
        For i = 0 To caseLinks.Length - 1
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 1) = caseLinks.item(i)
            linksAndIds(i + 1, 2) = Replace$(caseLinks.item(i), "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=", vbNullString)
        Next

        For i = LBound(linksAndIds, 1) To UBound(linksAndIds, 1)

            newURL = "https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=false" '"https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-cds/CaseForm.aspx?ViewPage&xsl=Case.xsl&tab=Crash&form=CaseForm&baseNode=&vehnum=-1&occnum=-1&pos=-1&pos2=-1&websrc=true&title=Crash%20Overview%20-%20Summary&caseid=" & linksAndIds(i, 2) & "&year=&fullimage=false"
            .Navigate2 newURL

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Dim tables As Object, arr()

            Set tables = .document.querySelectorAll("table")
            arr = Array(0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ws.NAME = linksAndIds(i, 2)

            For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                clipboard.SetText tables.item(arr(j)).outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells(LastRow(ws) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
            Next
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Public Function LastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: If we can narrow down the table indices of interest then we can probably write something that gives a nicer output format.

Comment: Thanks again QHarr. I tried your code and it is definitely a possibility to stop duplicates by using an array, but since the table.length changes for each case I guess I would be leaving out information.

Comment: Depends whether the indices for the tables of interest remain constant. Effectively I am filtering tables out. It looked like the indices were constant across the few cases I examined properly but you can have a closer look.

Comment: Did the indices turn out to be constant?

Comment: Up to index 11 of the array the tables seem to contain the same information among all cases. After that an undefined amount of images are listed for each case, leading to an offset in the index which, unfortunately, prevents me from getting more than the basic information up to index 11. I will try to use some keywords to figure out the individual offset until another pattern is found.

Comment: Did you need any info after the images? I deliberately stopped at 11. After that using instr on outerhtml might help with key word searching.

Comment: Yes, I do need additional information. Since I want to save all cases in a CSV I need to think about a format anyway, which is halfway to looking for keywords I suppose. Therefore I will spend some time to figure out what exactly I need and fill out the information with some hard coded keywords. Thank you again QHarr!